The returned latency value is higher than the set timeout, why is that?
I'm using the fastping-rs library to ping some IP addresses and get their latency. I am creating my pinger as such:
let (pinger, results) = match Pinger::new(Some(timeout), None) {
        Ok((pinger, results)) => (pinger, results),
        Err(e) => panic!("Error creating pinger: {}", e),
    };
    println!("Pinger created with timeout of {} ms", timeout);

My timeout is a u64 value set to 500 (milliseconds). The code of fastping-rs indicates that this value should be in milliseconds, so nothing wrong here (i think).
However, when I run the code, I get latency values that are over the set timeout.
102.165.35.33 is up with latency 763. Host is 102.165.35.33
102.165.35.67 is up with latency 773. Host is 102.165.35.67
102.165.35.56 is up with latency 773. Host is 102.165.35.56

The pinger is ran as follows after setting my list of addresses:
. . .
pinger.ping_once();
    loop {
        match results.recv() {
            Ok(result) => match result {
                Idle { addr } => {
                    . . .
                }
                Receive { addr, rtt } => {
                    let v4addr = Ipv4Addr::from_str(&addr.to_string()).unwrap();
                    let props = IpProperties {
                        ip: v4addr,
                        up: true,
                        latency: rtt,
                        hostname: gethostname(v4addr),
                    };
                    println!("{} is up with latency {}. Host is {}", v4addr, props.latency.as_millis(), props.hostname);
                    . . .

                }
            },
            Err(_) => panic!("Worker threads disconnected before the solution was found!"),
        }
    }
. . .

Am I doing something wrong ? Is this behavior normal ? Thank you !

Note that round trip time (rtt) is not the same as latency. RTT is the time between sending a ping and getting the response, while latency is the time between sending a ping and the peer receiving it, i.e. half RTT.

@SteffenUllrich according to that latency: rtt one has used latency term for rtt

@nlouis56 add timeout into output to be sure. If it's reproducible, you can always fill an issue on GH page
